# PHP Get IP based on host name

Tags: c#, php, ip

I have to implement a solution from `WinApp` written in `C#` to `PHP`. I need to extract the `IP` based on the `host name`. The below piece of code works perfectly:

```
IPHostEntry LocalHostIPEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);
IPAddress LocalHostIP = LocalHostIPEntry.AddressList[0];
string ipfromhost = LocalHostIP.ToString();
```

The only option I've found so far in `PHP` is:

```
gethostbyname('hostname');
```

But that returns a different `IP` for the same host than the `C#` code. Furthermore, the `IP` it returns is incorrect. If I check the related host using `nslookup -IPaddress-` then I get a totally different hostname.

What's going on? What other methods could be used to lookup the `IP` of a `host` on the network using `PHP`?

Comment: Is this error occurring with all the hostnames you try? You said you're on an internal network, what happens when you check externally? What about gethostbynamel (gets a list if host has multiple IPs)? Also, gethostbyname uses the resolver library of the underlying OS (Linux/Windows) - not sure how C#'s version operates. Finally, if you do find you're querying the incorrect DNS there's a Pear library for that: http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2

Comment: It seems like it could be a machine-specific problem: can you try the same code (and `nslookup`) from a different machine on the same network? Alternatively, from a virtual machine or live Linux distro?

Comment: Is this for reverse DNS lookups only or are you trying to get general DNS?

Answer (score 5):

you can use the [php dns_get_record function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)

```
array dns_get_record ( string $hostname [, int $type = DNS_ANY [, array &$authns [, array &$addtl [, bool &$raw = false ]]]] )
```

And then look in the array for a record of type A (means IPv4)

Comment: This returns a multidimensional `array` containing 2 `subarrays`. Both contains an `A` type record. The first one is the same (wrong) as in the `gethostbyname()`. The second one is also incorrect. `nslookup` doesn't return anything for it.

Comment: strange what hostname do you try to get? probably your dns settings are corrupted?

Comment: It's just the name of a computer on the corporate network. Probably DNS issue, but then how is it possible that the other code returns the correct value?

Comment: hm do you have more than one dns server? perhaps it can be better to ask the dns server in your network to get the ips. it can also be that you use DHCP, than you dont have name to ip, even if the computers try to communicate a hostname.

Comment: Well... yes we use DHCP as well. But again, if that would be a problem then no code could get the real IP,  right?

Comment: hm, it would be very hard to get a solution. and it depens on your getway and or your router. One of them has a list von ips to hostnames/computernames, but this list ist normally not well updated... so woth out a dns server and/or static ips, i would say no way...

Comment: @fishmong3r, it all depends on how your network is configured. Those two functions should work just great for Internet host names, but locally they could produce unexpected results.

Comment: You may wish to consult your network administrator to find out how your network is configured and what is the proper way to get IP address of the host.

Comment: I'm waiting for the response of the network team. But according to the manuals `dns_get_record` theoretically works the way as `Dns.GetHostEntry`. Therefore I would expect the same result on the same network.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 Solution to get Host IP using 2 predefined functions

```
$ip = gethostbyname('php.net');
echo $ip;

$result = dns_get_record("php.net");
print_r($result);
```

Will work it out when you have access to those sites through your firewall. it they blocked then you will see your local ip instead of the desired site IP.

Comment: can i use the same functions in C#.? will they work.?

Comment: You cant use any C# function in PHP